# Can I make NSubstitute throw an exception by default when calling an unmocked method?

Tags: unit-testing, nsubstitute

This is sometimes called strict-mode.

Here is a situation where this feature would be useful:
I caught a bunch of unit tests with false passes in my project. This is why:

1. To unit test some module, one of the dependencies needed to be mocked and its method was supposed to return null.
2. The Developer mocked the correct method, returning null, and the test passed.
3. Many weeks later, the module's internal implementation changed, and a different method was being called, requiring to be mocked and also to return null.
4. But due to NSubstitute's default behavior of returning default / null value to unmocked method calls, the unit tests continued to PASS, but by mistake, and nobody was the wiser. They should have FAILED, warning the Developer that his changes to the module's implementation did not satisfy the unit test mapped behavior.

I only discovered that the unit test was not testing correctly after the QA team reported a bug.

This was the test that worked originally and stopped working.

```
    [Fact]
public async void Handle_EntityNotFound_Throws()
{
    var request = new GetConfigTemplateRequest();
    var repository = Substitute.ForPartsOf<IRepository<ConfigTemplate>>();
    repository.GetItemAsync(Arg.Any<string>())
        .ReturnsNull();
    var requestHandler = new GetConfigTemplateRequestHandler(repository);

    var action = () => requestHandler.Handle(request, CancellationToken.None);

    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<EntityNotFoundException>(action);
}
```

This was the test fix.. it needs to mock a different method.

```
    [Fact]
public async void Handle_EntityNotFound_Throws()
{
    var request = new GetConfigTemplateRequest();
    var repository = Substitute.ForPartsOf<IRepository<ConfigTemplate>>();
    repository.GetDifferentItemAsync(/*some special condition*/)
        .ReturnsNull();
    var requestHandler = new GetConfigTemplateRequestHandler(repository);

    var action = () => requestHandler.Handle(request, CancellationToken.None);

    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<EntityNotFoundException>(action);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, NSubstitute doesn't have this feature, as explained [here](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/219) and [here](https://groups.google.com/g/nsubstitute/c/AdGTfszewtA).

> As a fairly clumsy workaround you could strictly check calls after the
> fact using sub.ReceivedCalls(), which will return all the calls the
> substitute received. You could query this enumerable and make sure it
> only contains the calls you expect. For example, to check a substitute
> was not called at all you can do
> Assert.AreEqual(sub.ReceivedCalls().Count(), 0);.